# Manipulate Office Add-In variable in Browser console

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've written an Outlook web addin, and I wan't to enable extended diagnostics in the browser console.

If something goes wrong I wan't to set the diagnostic level on my Logger class.

I assign the logger class to a variable declared in a script block in the addin html file

```js
<script>
    var Logger;
//...
```

However I can't access (or find) this variable from the console when running in the Outlook Web Application.

Comment: Can you check whether you have selected add-in's iframe as the [execution context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console) ?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thanks, I thought I already were in the Context. But double checking helps ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenter said. I was in the Wrong Context. Setting the console context to the iFrame was the solution.